# The usage of "savor" in The Great Gatsby

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In Chapter 1 of *The Great Gatsby*, part of a sentence went like this:

> ... a national figure in a way, one of those men who reach such an acute limited excellence at twenty-one that everything afterward savors of anti-climax.

I went to [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and searched for `[savor].[v*] of` and it gave nothing, meaning that in contemporary usage, "savor" as a verb is never followed by an "of." I know that today we usually say "savor something" instead of "savor of something," so does that mean it is a deprecated usage of the word "savor" in that sentence?

Comment: NOAD lists this under _savor_ as a verb: _(savor of) have a suggestion or trace of (something, esp. something bad)_. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/savor) shows something similar under Defs 6 & 7. [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/savor) reports a 1913 dictionary reading: _v. to have a particular smell or taste; -- with of; to partake of the quality or nature; to indicate the presence or influence; to smack; -- with of._

Comment: Just as *you can taste the soup* or *the soup can taste of onions*.

Comment: Before going to the COCA, go to the nearest dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you "savour something", you are referring to the item you are actually (typically) tasting.

When you use "savour of something", you are discussing the *charteristics* of the item you have just tasted.

Note definition #5 for the verb, as given in [Chambers Dictionary](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=savour&title=21st):

> **savour** or (*US*) **savor**
>   ***noun***
>   1. the characteristic taste or smell of something.
>   2. a faint but unmistakable quality.
>   3. a hint or trace.
>   4. relish or enjoyment.
>   ***verb*** (***savoured, savouring***)
>   1. to taste or smell with relish.
>   2. to take pleasure in something.
>   3. to flavour or season.
>   4. to relish.
>   5. (chiefly **savour of something**) to show signs of it; to smack of it.
>   **savourless** ***adj***
>   ***ETYMOLOGY:*** 13c: from French *savour*, from Latin *sapor*, from *sapere* to taste.

In your quotation

> everything afterward savors of anti-climax

the use of "savours of" is correct because you are describing the *characteristics* of "everything": you are not referring to the *item* having those characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Though unusual, I wouldn't say the usage is deprecated:  "smells and savors of the season", "which savors of politics", but surely there be an ill savor", . . .

.............................

From The Barnhart Concise Dictionary of Etyomology:
savor n. Probably before 1200, savur agreeable flavor, taste, sweetness; . . . related to sapere to have a flavor . . .

.............................

cf savory

.............................

RH:  taste:  ref. to savor as syn.